# Set default application name locale when no localize resource available for selected language in preference

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

How to set specific application name when user has set preferred language and there is no bundle supported in the app.

For example,

my app has language support for italy ans spanish,

Now is has selected french then how can i set default application name for it.

right now behavior is OS scans for language bundle which app has according to preferred language array from top to bottom. If OS founds any bundle for language then it gets the app name from it.